# PHP - Execution Time Faster on indirect object creation

Tags: php, performance, performance-testing

I have 3 files with the following code:

```
Filename: TCObj.php

class TCObj {
    protected $objects;

    public function __construct(){
        $this->objects = array();
    }

    public function register_service($service) {
        if(!isset($this->objects[$service])) {
            $this->objects[$service] = new $service;
        }
        return $this->objects[$service];            
    }       
}

File Name: TObj.php

class TObj {
    public function __construct(){

    }

    public function hello() {
        echo "Hello!!!";
    }
}


test.php contains the following code: 

require_once("TCObj.php");  
require_once("TObj.php");

$start_time = microtime(true);
$o = new TCObj();
$p = $o->register_service("TObj");
$p->hello();
$end_time = microtime(true);
echo "<br />";
echo $end_time - $start_time;
```

When I was running the above code this is much faster than I was creating an object directly using the following code:

```
require_once("TObj.php");

$start_time = microtime(true);
$p = new TObj();    
$p->hello();
$end_time = microtime(true);
echo "<br />";
echo $end_time - $start_time;
```

Shouldn't this be the vice-versa? Or Am I checking the wrong way for analyzing the computation time? Please do mind my English as I'm not much of a speaker :(

I thought the latter will be faster but it was not the case when tested both on a server with 512 MB Ram and a single core ( Linux ) and also on a local system with 4GB RAM and 4 core(s) (windows)

What Am I doing wrong?

Comment: have you run your tests on a big number of executions or just one? Is the speed difference big?

Comment: @Kaddath Yes, I ran it multiple times and initially both script takes around 7.xxxx initially and after that Test.php reduces to around 1.xxxx - 4.xxxx but the direct one is always around 6.xxxx - 8.xxxx

Comment: I can't see much difference at all for a single iteration, `0.00014019012451172` compared with `0.00010490417480469` for PHP 7.2.0rc4; though to be expected, the first that instantiates 2 objects is fractionally slower.... but there's so much fluctuation

Comment: `0.00014400482177734` compared with `7.2002410888672E-5` for PHP 7.20rc3; and `5.9843063354492E-5` compared with `4.5061111450195E-5` for 7.2.0rc2.... the second is definitely faster in both cases

Comment: @MarkBaker I'm using PHP 7.0.0 on an digital ocean Ubuntu 16.04 OS, and I'm getting like this for 1st:

0.00015401840209961
2.288818359375E-5
0.00011491775512695
0.00076389312744141
0.0001378059387207
1.3113021850586E-5


And for the second script it goes to:

5.9604644775391E-6
2.598762512207E-5
6.9141387939453E-6
2.2172927856445E-5
2.0027160644531E-5
7.1525573730469E-6

Comment: @MarkBaker does this have anything to do with my configuration??

I'm not using any automated tools for running the test(s) actually.. I was running the test(s) manually using multiple page refreshes and there is no other script(s) running on the server as this is an exclusive test server for me to break things, so I won't mess up our production server..

 :D :P

Comment: I think it has to do with your misreading the figures.... every one of your figures has a shorter time for the second than for the first

Comment: Hi Mark, Sorry.... But I'm not sure if I follow you correctly.. :-| it will be great if you can help me understand..

Comment: Looking at the figures that you posted: `0.00015401840209961` from test1 (using register_service) is higher than `5.9604644775391E-6` from test2 (simple instantiation), so test2 executed faster; `0.00011491775512695`from test1 (using register_service) is higher than `6.9141387939453E-6` from test2 (simple instantiation), so test2 executed faster; `1.3113021850586E-5`from test1 (using register_service) is higher than `7.1525573730469E-6` from test2 (simple instantiation), so test2 executed faster; etc

Comment: @MarkBaker ohh.. now i get it :D It seems to be I'm not good at maths too.. My bad, I got it that E-6 means 10^6 which means that I have to add that much zero's in front of it so 5.9604644775391E-6 means it's actually 0.000000596044775391 which is way much faster than 0.00015401840209961

Thanks for the help :) [Thumbs Up]